# briefly vs succinctly

Tags: word-usage

As far as I know, when somebody is asked to elucidate an intricate topic in which he/she is specialist  and after explaining it in detail for a while, he/she says 'so in briefly' or 'if I put it in brief' at  the end of his/her talk in order to sum up the gist of the topic in one or two sentence for people who listen to but are baffled also.

Even though I wrote down some  examples of the usage of the word briefly, I am not sure if I use it correctly.So I would like to ask as to how to use the word briefly in these kind of scenarios.

And is the word succinclty snonym of the word briefly and how can we use it in similar way as the word briefly in our conversation or essays?

Comment: Why not share some of the examples you came up with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***in brief***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-brief) basically means *in short* or *in summary*.

[***succinct***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/succinct) is a bit different. It also implies *clarity* in the summary.

> *adjective*
>   1) **clearly** and briefly stated; terse

Not just a summary but clear, understandable and to the point.

Comment: +1. Your answer is not only brief, but succinct as well !